# Flutter: no versions of permission_handler match >5.1.0+2 <6.0.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-pub, flutter-upgrade

After upgrading Flutter and Dart to the latest versions I also updated the dependencies of my app. Now, when I run `flutter pub get` I get the following error:

```
Because no versions of permission_handler match >5.1.0+2 <6.0.0 and permission_handler 5.1.0+2 depends on permission_handler_platform_interface ^2.0.2, permission_handler ^5.1.0+2 requires permission_handler_platform_interface ^2.0.2.
And because no versions of permission_handler_platform_interface match >2.0.2 <3.0.0 and permission_handler_platform_interface 2.0.2 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.2, permission_handler ^5.1.0+2 requires plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.2.        
And because geolocator >=7.0.0 depends on geolocator_platform_interface ^2.0.0 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, permission_handler ^5.1.0+2 is incompatible with geolocator >=7.0.0.
So, because MyApp depends on both geolocator ^7.0.1 and permission_handler ^5.1.0+2, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_app...                             
pub get failed (1; So, because MyApp depends on both geolocator ^7.0.1 and permission_handler ^5.1.0+2, version solving failed.)
```

I do not quite understand where the error is and what I can do to fix it. If there is any information missing, I will add it as soon as I can. Does anyone have an idea what I need to change in the dependencies?

Here is my `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804], locale de-DE)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because this package doesn’t support null safety yet. I think you should rather create an issue on their GitHub repository instead of asking the question here.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I will definitely do that. Do you have an idea what I can do for now to be able to start my app again?

Comment: I found issues about this problem now after knowing where to search: 
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/468 and https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/464 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You’re welcome! You might encounter more packages who don’t support this. If so it’s best to remain on flutter 1.22.6 for now. You can call flutter downgrade to go back to the previous stable